# CSS :hover on mobile act as click

Tags: html, css, hover

I currently have a div with some information in it. See the example below:

```
<div class="verstuurd" onclick="alert('clicked!');">
    <div class="titel"><span>Title</span><img src="imageurl"/></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="imageurl"/></div>
    <div class="tekst"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div class="hover">
        VISIBLE TEXT
    </div>
    <div class="delen">
        VISIBLE AFTER HOVER
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The `:hover` function works perfectly and the "delen" part is shown and the "hover" part is hidden. I only got a problem on mobile devices. If I scroll down the page on a mobile device and I touch the div, the hover will be triggered.

The answer I am looking for is; how am I able to use `:hover` on PC's and some sort of click event on mobile devices? So that I have to click in order to change the content and a second click will trigger the onclick of the div.

As an example of my inspiration see the [website](http://www.wefashion.nl/en_en/men/jassen/?prefn1=runOutNL&pmin=0&prefv1=N).

If you hover an item it will show the heart icons. PC uses this with hover and mobile needs a click to be shown. Unfortunately I can't find the source code which triggers this.

Comment: Well, putting aside the fact that making your visitors clic two times to access the content is a terrible feature, you'll probably need to use javascript to do so.

Comment: You could make two elements, one for pc version, one for mobile and show/hide them using css media queries. Then for one you would have hover event and for other click event

Comment: @John :hover acts like a click (since you cannot hover on an item on a mobile device).

Comment: @YounesMgharfaoui True, but unfortunately when I'm scrolling on my iPhone and I touch the div it switches content. So that means the :hover is triggered. Two versions is not a problem at all, but is there a click event for css? :active and :focus just don't work like it should...

Comment: @Younes that's why I said there would be two elements for each version. For mobile you would have element for which you had to click two times, but for pc element with hover + click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about, you want an onClick="theFunctionNameToBeCalled()" fired when a div is touched (specifically on a mobile device?)

if you want that, you can use

```
$( "#divIdToBeTouced" ).click(function() {
  //do something with a function here
});
```

or you could use plain ol' JavaScript to do the task.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Coty's Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divIdToBeTouched" onmouseover="theFunctionToBeCalled()" onClick="theFunctionToBeCalled()">
I'm a div
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
function theFunctionToBeCalled(){
  i++;
  if(i == 2) {
    //do what you wanted once the onClick event was fired
    alert("i == 2");
    //now make sure to reset the flag that was made so it will work     next time
    i = 0;
  }
  else {
    //change the content
    alert("i == 1");
  }
    //do something interesting here if you want to
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

paste that code on this page http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default? and you can try it out on a browser computer
and try it on a mobile device and it should work
I tested it

Now make the hover event also call this function and it'll cover both evens

---

Extra info:

### I've heard arguments with two possible paths to go from here and some say one way is "dangerous", I'll list the sides below If you wanted to know...

cont'd

the other argument is there needs to be an event listener added instead of a direct function call
This seems more safe. I think because it can help hide the function call its self..? I'm not sure.

Hope this helps